# FireStore Data getting and storing it in an array

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I am fetching data from Cloud Firestore and I don't know hot to get the name and imageURl from the data I fetched.

Here is the code:

```
func getFireBaseData(){
    db.collection("categories").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err.localizedDescription)")
        } else {

            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {

                self.categoryDictionary.append(document.data())
            }
            self.tableVu.reloadData()
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: let category = document.get("name") as! String
have used this and solved

Comment: can you show waht you are getting in qwerSnapshot